# Autosys Job Failing

Tags: c#, .net, autosys

I have a .net app that does a variety of file operations. It has been scheduled via task manager and runs without issue. We are moving the job to be controlled by autosys and have the job configured. When it kicks off I see all the files move as expected and I get a log file indicating that everything ran as expected. The app is working. Autosysy, however, reports that it failed.

```
Status/[Event]  Time                 Ntry ES  ProcessTime           Machine
  --------------  --------------------- --  --  --------------------- ----------------------------------------
  RUNNING         09/26/2013  15:30:21   1  PD  09/26/2013 15:31:12   
  FAILURE         09/26/2013  15:31:59   1  PD  09/26/2013 15:32:17   
  [*** ALARM ***]
    JOBFAILURE    09/26/2013  15:32:16   1  PD  09/26/2013 15:32:17   
  [STARTJOB]      09/26/2013  16:00:00   0  UP
```

The application is a winform app  - here's the meat of the code:

```
    static int Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting processing...");
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                if (args.Length > 0) //if we call the app with args we do some stuff, otherwise we show the UI to let the user choose what to do
                {
                   //stuff happens here that works, other method calls, etc.               
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));    
                    Console.WriteLine("Process complete.");
                    return 0;
                }
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new FileLoader());
                return 0;
            }
```

The job IS working, it's doing everything that it is supposed to do without logging any exceptions BUT autosys still reports failure. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Autosys will mark the job as successfully completed when the process ends. In your case you've told that it is an Win-Form application. So what may happen here is the autosys is starting the Application and also the application is working fine and it is doing what it suppose to do. But the process will not end unless untill someone manually close the window application or if you have some techinque to close itself. And so Autosys is assuming that the process not ended thus marking the job as failed.

The solution for this is make your application as console application or else I remember there is one property when setting up the Autosys job not to consider the Process ending so the job will just start the program and mark the job as completed.